# Basic Touch ID Implementation

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I've been meaning to write a nested function which accepts the reason string for touchID and a bool value if it should be shown or not. This is my code

```
 import UIKit
 import LocalAuthentication  

 class XYZ : UIViewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        presentTouchID(reasonToDsiplay: "Are you the owner?", true) //ERROR: Expression resolves to an unused function
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func presentTouchID(reasonToDsiplay reason: String, _ shouldShow: Bool) -> (Bool) -> (){

        let reason1 = reason
        let show = shouldShow

        let long1 = { (shoudlShow: Bool) -> () in

            if show{
                let car = LAContext()

                let reason = reason1

                guard car.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) else {return}

                car.evaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {(success, error) in

                    guard error != nil else {return}

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { Void in

                        print("Kwaatle")

                    })

                }

            }
            else{
                print("Mah")
            }


        }
        return long1
    }
}
```

When I do `presentTouchID(reasonToDsiplay: "Are you the owner?", true)` in
`func viewDidLoad()` I get an error saying

> Expression resolves to an unused function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your method `presentTouchID` returns a closure / function. You call `presentTouchID` but do not use the returned closure in any way.

You have a few options here.
1. Call the returned closure:

```
presentTouchID(reasonToDsiplay: "Are you the owner?", true)(true)
```

which looks really really awkward.
2. You can store the returned closure in a variable:

```
let present = presentTouchID(reasonToDsiplay: "Are you the owner?", true)
```

I am not sure though if that makes any sense here.
3. You can remove the boolean as argument from the `presentTouchID`
4. **OR** fix the returned closure

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    presentTouchID(reasonToDsiplay: "Are you the owner?", true) { success in
        if success {
            print("Kwaatle")
        } else {
            print("Mah")
        }
    }
}

func presentTouchID(reasonToDsiplay reason: String, _ shouldShow: Bool, completion: (evaluationSuccessfull: Bool) -> ()) {

    if shouldShow {
        let car = LAContext()

        guard car.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) else {
            completion(evaluationSuccessfull: false)
            return
        }

        car.evaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {(success, error) in

            guard error != nil else {
                completion(evaluationSuccessfull: false)
                return
            }
            completion(evaluationSuccessfull: success)
        }

    } else{
        completion(evaluationSuccessfull: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: And @luk2302, this can also be thought of as a completion handler correct?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 yes, it very much is a completion handler.

Comment: Perfect. Does this happen to be a synchronous process aswell? Because I've read that synchronous processes freeze up the UI? I'm I wrong? @luk2302?